# How to fire select onchange event with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dropdown list:

```
<select size="1" name="filter"id="priority_filter" onchange="filter_user_trainings();">
   <option value="all">All</option>
   <option value="optional">Optional</option>
   <option value="mandatory">Mandatory</option>
   <option value="essential">Essential</option>
   <option value="custom">Custom</option>
</select>
```

In a `function` I call these:

```
if(db==0 || db==1 ||db==2)
{
   $("#priority_filter").val('custom');
}
```

I want to fire the `select` `onchange` function when the jQuery switches the value. How can I do this? The code above does not work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can call `change()` on `select` to first or `.trigger("change");`

```
if(db==0 || db==1 ||db==2)
{
   $("#priority_filter").val('custom');    
   $("#priority_filter").change();    
}
```

OR

```
if(db==0 || db==1 ||db==2)
{
   $("#priority_filter").val('custom').change();      
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 ..code..
$('#priority_filter').on('change', function(){
     ..do your stuff..
 } 
..code..

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
On load

```
 $("#priority_filter").change(function(){
    var val = $("#priority_filter").val();
    //alert(val);
    //your code
});
```

Demo Here:
http://jsfiddle.net/j8DPN/