# Trying to run function on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I have a custom function which is fired once I make a selection from a select list.

**Here is my select list:**

```
<select id="payment_type" name="payment_type" onchange="java_script_:show(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
            <option id="default" value="" <cfif #get_ticket.payment_type# eq ''>selected="selected"</cfif>>Please select the payment type</option>
            <option id="check" value="check" <cfif #get_ticket.payment_type# eq 'check'>selected="selected"</cfif>>Check</option>
            <option id="cash" value="cash" <cfif #get_ticket.payment_type# eq 'check'>selected="selected"</cfif>>Cash</option>
            <option id="visa" value="visa" <cfif #get_ticket.payment_type# eq 'visa'>selected="selected"</cfif>>Visa</option>
            <option id="mc" value="mc" <cfif #get_ticket.payment_type# eq 'mc'>selected="selected"</cfif>>Master Card</option>
            <option id="amex" value="amex" <cfif #get_ticket.payment_type# eq 'amex'>selected="selected"</cfif>>American Express</option>
            <option id="discover" value="discover" <cfif #get_ticket.payment_type# eq 'discover'>selected="selected"</cfif>>Discover Card</option>
          </select>
```

My javascript function will show or hide DIVs in my page based on my selection.

**Here is that JS code:**

```
<SCRIPT>          
$( document ).ready(function() {
console.log("My Function was called on page load"); 
    function show(select_item) {
       console.log( select_item);
        if (select_item == "check") {
            $("##check_number").css("display", "block");
            $("##card_number").css("display", "none");
            $("##card_name").css("display", "none");
            $("##expiration_date").css("display", "none");
            $("##cvc_code").css("display", "none");
            $('##submitPaymentForm').prop('disabled', false);
            $('##submitPaymentForm').prop('disabled', false);           
        }
        if (select_item == "cash") {
            $("##check_number").css("display", "none");
            $("##card_number").css("display", "none");
            $("##card_name").css("display", "none");
            $("##expiration_date").css("display", "none");
            $("##cvc_code").css("display", "none");
            $('##submitPaymentForm').prop('disabled', false);           
        } 
        if (select_item == "visa") {
            $("##check_number").css("display", "none");
            $("##card_number").css("display", "block");
            $("##card_name").css("display", "block");
            $("##expiration_date").css("display", "block");
            $("##cvc_code").css("display", "block");
            $('##submitPaymentForm').prop('disabled', false);           
        } 
        if (select_item == "mc") {
            $("##check_number").css("display", "none");
            $("##card_number").css("display", "block");
            $("##card_name").css("display", "block");
            $("##expiration_date").css("display", "block");
            $("##cvc_code").css("display", "block");
            $('##submitPaymentForm').prop('disabled', false);           
        } 
        if (select_item == "amex") {
            $("##check_number").css("display", "none");
            $("##card_number").css("display", "block");
            $("##card_name").css("display", "block");
            $("##expiration_date").css("display", "block");
            $("##cvc_code").css("display", "block");
            $('##submitPaymentForm').prop('disabled', false);           
        } 
        if (select_item == "discover") {
            $("##check_number").css("display", "none");
            $("##card_number").css("display", "block");
            $("##card_name").css("display", "block");
            $("##expiration_date").css("display", "block");
            $("##cvc_code").css("display", "block");
            $('##submitPaymentForm').prop('disabled', false);           
        }  
        if(select_item == "") {
            $("##check_number").css("display", "none");
            $("##check_number").css("display", "block");
            $("##card_number").css("display", "block");
            $("##card_name").css("display", "block");
            $("##expiration_date").css("display", "block");
            $("##cvc_code").css("display", "block");
            $('##submitPaymentForm').prop('disabled', false);           
        }
    }
show($("##payment_type").val());
});

</SCRIPT>
```

I am trying to run this script not just when a selection is made but also when the page is loaded because sometimes a user is coming back to this page after already making the selection and I want the proper DIVs to already be shown or hidden.

It works fine if my selectlist call the function but it is currently not running my function on page load.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are *defining* the function in document.ready. If you also want to execute it, you need to [trigger the select element's change event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945267/how-to-fire-select-onchange-event-with-jquery). See also [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: I believe I am triggering the onChange with this: onchange="java_script_:show(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" . Am I not?

Comment: Nope.  That will only call the function when the user changes the selection. If you also want to invoke it onLoad, you must use trigger() or change().

Comment: I'm not familar with trigger(). Would that be defined in my selectlist?

Comment: No. To trigger that code when the page loads, invoke the trigger() function inside document.ready(). Though typically, you would define the change function with jQuery too. See the examples on the trigger link above.

Comment: OK, I updated question with the my edited code once again. I'm getting udefined in my console output. I'm assuming it doesn't like my values that I am trying to pass in?

Comment: What's this got to do with ColdFusion? (Am I missing something, but this is a JS question, innit?)

Comment: I got it. I forgot to add an ID to my selectlist, just have the name property defined. Coldfusion always gets me as it doesn't require the ID property. I added it in and now my posted code works. I'll update my original code.

Comment: (Edit) BTW, it is not mandatory, but since you are using jQuery anyway ... you could also bind the change event rather than using `<select onChange>`.  [See JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k6sLsdyz/1/).

Comment: Thanks Leigh. That is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You defined a function in a `document.ready()` section, but haven't called it. Add a call to your function in the end of the `document.ready()`, like `show(<param>);`

Comment: I am recieving now: Uncaught ReferenceError: show is not defined. I've updated my code with my edits.

Comment: Which line produces that error? Btw, the [id selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) should contain only one symbol '#'.

Comment: *should contain only one symbol '#'* True. However, in CF pound signs are reserved characters. In some situations they must be escaped ie `##` to produce a literal pound sign ie `#`.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem, `windows.onload`

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function codeAddress() {
            alert('ok');
        }
        window.onload = codeAddress;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body> </html>
```