# How do I change color with the help of AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Given a drop-down list of colors.

When the `onchange` event is fired by the drop down, the color should be changed with AJAX help.

That means, the page should not be reloaded, it should display the selected color without loading, or reloading.

jQuery AJAX must be implemented.

How do I do this?

Comment: There's no question here - just a requirement list that sounds like a homework task. Also note that AJAX would have nothing to do with changing a colour on a page when a select is changed

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code instead imperative demands

Comment: Why use Ajax to change color? There is no server side needed to change a color http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945267/how-to-fire-select-onchange-event-with-jquery

Comment: I feel like @devil here is a troll, he already has the "Peer Pressure" badge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You want to use JQuery only. 
Ajax is for sending data to server and receiving a response. Unless You want to save a change in your DB there is no need to use AJAX.

```
$('#dropdownId').change(function(){ 
    $('body').css('background-color', $(this).val()); 
});
```